# ArrayList and Doubles

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I have a BINGO game that has a button that acts as the caller. Each time I click the button I want a randomized number between 1-75.
I have the following code to try and eliminate the duplicates but I have no idea on how to move on from here. I basically need to remove the number from the ArrayList for the next time I click the button.

```
private JButton c; {
    c = new JButton("Call");
    c.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int i = 1; i <= 75; i++){
                    list.add(i);
                }

                Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Comment: Do you really want to shuffle every time the button is hit?  If I'm not missing something, I'd think you can shuffle once every time a new game is started, and then just set up an index that steps through the list every time the button is pressed.

Comment: ajb has it right; once the list is shuffled, just use the (already randomized) list as is.  Towards that end, you'd want to move the initialization and .shuffle() call out of the actionPerformed() code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a LinkedList instead of an Arraylist, populate it in the constructor and then let the LinkedList do all the work for you.  Something like:

```
public class Bingo extends JPanel{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5791572059409665801L;
  private LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  private JButton c = new JButton("Call");

  public Bingo(){
    for(int ii=1; ii<= 75; ii++)
      list.add(ii);
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(list.poll());
      }
    });

    add(c);
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Bingo bingoClass = new Bingo();
    bingoClass.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(bingoClass);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String... args){
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it wont let me do Collections.shuffle(queue)
The method shuffle(List<?>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Queue<Integer>)

Comment: No need to use a queue, use an `ArrayList` and remove every time the last element, something like `list.remove(list.size() - 1)`.

Comment: even if the shuffle worked the priority queue will give the integers in order 1-75.

Comment: @Flavio I was using an ArrayList, I just don't know how to approach on losing the last element. That line wont remove the number that is just used though if I'm correct...

Comment: @HassaanHafeez my fault, I didn't look closely enough at Collections.shuffle, I've update the answer with a list implementation.

Comment: @Grammin do I need that code in a for loop? Because using that code allows me to click the Call Button once (A random Number appears) then if I click it again I get errors.

Comment: @HassaanHafeez, last edit, finally got the right data structure! LinkedList is what you want.

Comment: @Grammin Why does it only let me click the button once? On my 2nd+ click I get a bunch of errors. EDIT: Oops seems I had to change a few stuff up Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @HassaanHafeez, I've updated the code with my full working example.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Grammin Sorry for the annoyance, seems I had to change a few stuff up Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Oh one more thing if you're not to busy. I've had this error
"The serializable class BingoHelper does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of 
 type long" and then I saw the second line of your code and I input that into my code and that problem fixed. Although it did not stop my program from working I was just wondering what it meant.

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/serialization-in-java.html

Comment: You can also suppress the warning by doing:  @SuppressWarnings("serial") before your class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of element to be removed :

```
int indexToRemove = list.indexOf(numberToRemove);
```

Then remove the object at that index in the list

```
list.remove(indexToRemove);
```